# How to use ffdhe2048 in node js?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I am reading about Diffie Hellman key exchange from [Real World Cryptography](https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-cryptography) book and came across this

> For this reason, best practice nowadays is to use [RFC 7919](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919), which defines
> several groups of different sizes and security. For example, ffdhe2048 is the group
> defined by the 2,048-bit prime modulus.

I want to use the recommended group in nodejs and i am not sure what the modp number should be.

Looking at the [relevant section](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-diffiehellmangroup) of the documentation for node crypto module, I see the function `createDiffieHellmanGroup` can be called passing in the modp number, with reference being made to [rfc2412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412.txt) and [rfc3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt) where some modp numbers are defined for some groups.

Thing is i cant find any modp number defined in rfc7919. How then can I use the group specified in the rfc?

Comment: This is a library issue of NodeJS, however, the modp is on the [appendix A-1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919#appendix-A.1)

Comment: "has registry value 256"?
 so 256?

Comment: What do you understand from [registry value](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7919#section-1)?